# Argument labels '(name:)' do not match any available overloads (Swift)

Tags: swift, struct

I have this struct

```
struct QCategoryy {
    var name:String
    var image:UIImage
    var isSelected = false
    init(name:String, image:UIImage) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
    }
}

extension QCategoryy: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.name = value
    }
    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(name: value)
    }
    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(name: value)
    }
}
```

but i don't know why, after i added `var image` and in the init `self.image = image`  i get in the extension at the lines `self.init(name: value)` the error: Argument labels '(name:)' do not match any available overloads. How can i solve it?

EDIT

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Alamofire

class NearbyPlaces {
    static func getCategories() -> [QCategoryy] {
        let list:[QCategoryy] = [QCategoryy(name: "Art_gallery", image: UIImage(named: "art_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Bar", image: UIImage(named: "bar_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name :"Night_club", image: UIImage(named: "nightclub_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Movie_theater", image: UIImage(named: "cinema_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Restaurant", image: UIImage(named: "restaurant_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Gym", image: UIImage(named: "gym_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Spa", image: UIImage(named: "spa_button.png")!), QCategoryy(name: "Museum", image: UIImage(named: "museum_button.png")!)]
        return list
    }
```

Comment: You don't have an `init(name:)` – but even if you did, what would you expect the value of the `image` property to be?

Comment: @Hamish so how can i add in the extension the image property? if you look at my edited question i add a list that i created for a tableView, so now i have this problem because i'm trying to add the images in the tableView cells

Comment: What do you need the extension for? You're not using it in your `getCategories()` function.

Comment: @Connor ok but how can i adjust the error Argument labels '(name:)' do not match any available overloads ?

Comment: @Connor i need the extension to send request about nearby places, it work with the classes of swiftyJSON

Comment: I would stop worrying about "fixing" the error and step back and understand it first. You have a `UIImage` property that is not optional. It needs to be set to something. In your extension, you are initializing a `QCategoryy` without doing that. So depending on what you *want* to do, maybe that UIImage should be optional, or maybe you should specify a default value for it.

Comment: @Connor you are right, what i only want to do is to add the images to the list of category like here [QCategoryy(name: "Art_gallery", image: UIImage(named: "art_button.png")!) because i want that in the tableView cells, each name has also his specific image. Before i did this my list has only string like this  list:[QCategory] = ["Bakery", "Doctor", "School" etc.]